# Find out which app is making internet request

Tags: networking, sony-xperia, android-10

I'm tracing my network's DNS calls for a few days (using Pi-Hole to block ads and tracking) and I noticed that on my phone, something is calling `checkip.amazonaws.com` every 5-10 minutes. As I find this rather odd, I've been trying to find out which app is doing this and why.

I am running non-rooted Android 10. I tried with Packet Capture (which does not work at all due to SSL issue) and HttpCanary (which does not work too well due to SSL issue). HttpCanary does not show anything (not even SSL errors) during the time of the DNS request. I'm tempted to simply block this URL entirely but I'd really rather find out where it is coming from. So far, I'm puzzled where to look next.

Comment: You could redirect the DNS name to a local TCP port that is open but no real server is attached (server does not send anything. should be possible to simulate e.g. using `socat`). This delays the TLS handshake phase which is performed of course using an open TCP connection. I would assume that the connection may be open ~30 seconds without response (untested). As the request is performed periodically you can wait for it and and use netstat on the device to identify the process id that creates this connection and thus identify the app.

Comment: Good thought but doesn't work for the same reason: Android 10 got way too restrictive (which, generally, is a good thing I guess). I got lots of permission denied running netstat. Seems like available apps also do not work from 10 onwards.

Comment: But what should still work is redirecting `checkip.amazonaws.com` to a different HTTPS IP address so that the TLS connection handshake fails. May be if the apps is not well developed you will see the error message/stack trace on `adb logcat` (which also includes the PID).

Comment: unfortunately nothing in logcat either... WIll leave the bogus redirect for now.

Comment: My last idea: Extract all APK files from your device (e.g. via `adb backup`or any other tool that can extract multiple APK files from a device). Copy the apk files to a PC, unzip them all each to an own directory and make a full-text search (e.g. grep) for `checkip.amazonaws.com` on them. If you are lucky the dns name is stored in plain text within the app and you will be able to identify the app.

Comment: pulled all apks, did a grep, no result. However, I noticed that the local logcat did not have enough permissions. In Android Studio I got knocked out by the amount of logs and was unable to find anything here after some deeper search as well.

Comment: I meanwhile noticed that not all apps allow being backed up (e.g. Facebook, Whatsapp, Instagram). MIght be one of these then, wouldn't be too suprising.